# Add error when delete data in Yii 1

Tags: php, yii, crud

I'm using default delete of Yii. And I just want soft delete a row, it's mean I keep that row and update column `deleted` from `0` to `1`.

That my code in Controller:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    if (Posts::model()->countByAttributes(['category_id' => $model->id]) == 0) {
        $model->deleted = 1;
        $model->update();
    }
    if (!isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
}
```

Now I just want if Post have any category, it will show popup cannot delete this Post.

Any solutions about this?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh... usualy you would add errors in the validator. Honestly that is the best advice... well the Yii way. You could just check if $_POST is set, mass assign $_POST to $model->attributes and then let model worry about validation. What I would do next is write a custom but simple validation function in the model that would check if there are categories for said model and if yes return true, otherwise false. Then you would just do:

```
if($model->validate())
{
    $model->delete = 1;
    if($model->update)
    {
       // do whatever you wanna do redirect/render...
    }
    else {
       Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', "Unable to delete post");
       // render or redirect... flash is more for redirect but it'll do the trick
    }
}
```

This would solve the backend of it. In the view file you need to display this flash. In the view that you render if it's not deleted add this piece of code:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('error')):?>
     <div class="info">
          <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error'); ?>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would do it this way... you can do whatever you want to do